# Web API: FromBody always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to develop a web API, and when I test the POST method, the body is always null. I have tried everything when sending the request:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1748/api/SomeAPI");
req.Method = "post";;

var aaa = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Test");
req.ContentType = "application/xml";
req.ContentLength = aaa.Length;
req.GetRequestStream().Write(aaa, 0, aaa.Length);

HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream())) {
    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

I use a breakpoint, and the API is called properly, but the body member is always null:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]String test) {

}
```

Comment: Previously, I've split out the GetRequestStream() so that I can call Close() on it.

Comment: @RobLang: I already tried that, but still getting null

Comment: Try to use sniffer - like HTTP analyzer to check your request,seems like something goes wrong with the request. You can try to use chrome advance rest client to send sample request.

Comment: @Vladimir: The body is part of the request, but now fetched by the web api

Comment: Just curious, have you already tried debugging the API end to see what Request.Content looks like? You should be able to at least take a glance and see if the length matches what you're expecting. If the length matches, Web API is probably just not pulling the data into your parameter automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your Content Type is set to XML so you must pass the data as XML. This means wrapping your data in `<string>` element.

I would recommend using RestSharp (http://restsharp.org/) for making WebAPI calls from .Net.

```
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:1748/");
        var request = new RestRequest("api/SomeAPI", Method.POST);
        request.AddBody("Test");
        var response = client.Execute(request);
```

**Update**

I have created a sample project and it works absolutely fine:

**Server side:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/TestAPI")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]String test)
        {
            return Ok(string.Format("You passed {0}.", test));
        }
    }
}
```

**Client side:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1748/api/TestAPI");
            req.Method = "post"; ;
            var aaa = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("\"Test\"");
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.ContentLength = aaa.Length;
            req.GetRequestStream().Write(aaa, 0, aaa.Length);
            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After installing the WEB API service in IIS and running the console app it prints:

`"You passed Test."`

Please note the quotes around the response.
If you want to use XML then you need to modify the content type and data you are sending:

```
var aaa = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">Test</string>");
```

The response you will get is

`<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">You passed Test.</string>`

Both samples in the debugger will have correct value passed in the test parameter.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if it is XML, JSON, Plain Text. What matters is that the body is always null no matter what. I'm suspecting it's bug or something.

Comment: In your example the body will be `Test`. When it reaches the server it will need to deserialize it. As content type is XML it will try to interpret it as XML and will fail,So it will assume you have not passed any data and will pass NULL to your method. If you want to access the raw content of your body (i.e. the string) please read this article: [https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/dec/13/accepting-raw-request-body-content-with-aspnet-web-api](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/dec/13/accepting-raw-request-body-content-with-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: By The way, JSON would fail for the same reason - in JSON strings are surrounded by quotes so in order to make it work with JSON you need to use  var aaa = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("\"Test\"");
Your method will then receive Test

Comment: It's does not work, and it seems to be a bug. I found a topic in Gidhub indicating that is a bug. It has absolutely nothing to do with the content type, if that is a problem, you will get an error not null value :)

Comment: Please see the working solution in the updated answer.

Comment: I solved it, it appeared to be an encoding problem. Through using the right encoding and specifying it in the content type, the problem was finally solved.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[HttpPost]
public void SomeApi()
{
   var test = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Test"];
}
```

If u send correctly the value,this will work 100%

Answer (score -2):

Two things to try, 1st, try your request using a tried and tested tool like Postman. This will eliminate any chance your request is malformed in any way. 2nd, try changing your ContentType to text/plain. It's possible the request pipeline is seeing application/xml  but your request body is invalid xml which really should be a bad request but is just being serialized as null.